# How to solve "incorrect username or password"?

Tags: reddit

I  suffer [this same glitch](https://www.reddit.com/r/bugs/comments/m9knil/locked_out_of_account_with_error_incorrect). What's wrong? How do I correct this?

On 1 Oct 2023, Reddit suddenly signed me out when I was typing a comment. See screenshot below. But I know my WiFi was working, because I was streaming SoundCloud which kept playing music perfectly, and because my husband (on the same WiFi) kept speaking to his friend on Zoom normally.

And I know my password, because it is my maiden name all in lower case. I typed correctly.  After retyping my password several times, and several failed attempts to  log back in, I requested the password reset email that worked. Then I successfully changed the password. Then I tried to log in again with the new password. But Reddit STILL doesn't work! The screenshot below kept resurfacing. Clearly, my password is correct, as I changed it!

[image]

Many Redditors suffer this same glitch.

| Link | Date |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| Can't log in to my other account: "incorrect username or password". I reset the password multiple times with different passwords, none of them worked. What's the problem? | 13 Jan 2022 |
| Incorrect username or password? | 16 Feb 2022 |
|  |  |
| [Reddit says Incorrect username or password when I try to log in on Edge or Chrome.](https://redd.it/szhua6) | 23 Feb 2022 |
| [Incorrect username or password on one PC but not others](https://redd.it/12dxix3) | 6 Apr 2023 |
| [Incorrect Username Or Password](https://redd.it/12szfot) | 20 Apr 2023 |
| [Says “incorrect username or password” no matter what](https://redd.it/128k7zt) | 1 Apr 2023 |
| [Incorrect username or password](https://redd.it/15ojden) | 11 Aug 2023 |
| [Incorrect username or password](https://redd.it/15orwxx) | 12 Aug 2023 |
| [I keep getting "incorrect username or password" after putting the correct one.](https://redd.it/16ndlvk) | 20 Sep 2023 |

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting questions are off-topic on Web Applications SE. Checkout [security.se] and [su], they allow this kind of questions but first checkout their how to ask troubleshooting questions guidelines.

Comment: It's an awful practice to use names as passwords, even if the names are uncommon because they are written in documents that might be retrieved from public records and leaked files. If your new passwords are similar, you should seriously consider spending some time ASAP to learn the basics about Internet safety.

Comment: Edits should be done with the intention to improve the question to make it a good fit for Web Applications. A question like this is unlikely to be fixed due to the scope of this site. As it was mentioned in the previous comment, there are other sites where a troubleshooting question might be on topic.